# extjs4 treepanel behaviour issue

Tags: extjs4, treepanel

i am working in extjs4. I have treeview as-
[image: MyTree view]

store is loading json values correctly in treeview. But when i am clciking on treenodes its expanding only once and if we click again its giving error as-
"TypeError: listener.fireFn is undefined".And treenodes are not getting expanded again.
i have treeview code as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbquestion.tree1', {

    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    //title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
   id:'tree1',
    height: 150,
   // floating:true,
    alias : 'widget.tree1',
    //store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('qb.qbquestionStore'),
    store:'qb.qbquestionStore',
    displayField: 'text',
    rootVisible : true,
    multiSelect : true,
    valueField:'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
```

And treestore as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.store.qb.qbquestionStore',{

        extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

        model: 'Balaee.model.qb.QbquestionModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        constructor: function() {

            Ext.apply(this,{
                proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url: 'index.php/qbquestion/getCategory'
                },
                root: {
                    text: 'Main',
                    id: 'src',
                    expanded: true
                }
            });

            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
});
```

So how to overcome this